# rails undefine method size nil class for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i tried to have this in my navaigation which will show products in cart

```
 <% if !@order_item.nil? && @order_item.errors.any? %>
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
        <% @order_item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <% if @order_items.size == 0%>
      <p class="text-center">
        There are no items in your shopping cart.  Please <%= link_to "go back", root_path %> and add some items to your cart.
      </p>
    <% else %>
      <% @order_items.each do |order_item| %>
        <%= render 'carts/cart_row', product: order_item.product, order_item: order_item, show_total: true %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

after adding this to the navigation when i visit other pages it fail but when the cart page it works. how can i show this in every page?

Comment: In which controller you have written : order_items & order_item . Please make sure that these are accessible within every controller at a  common place

Comment: they are availabe in the carts controller. how can i add it to the application controller?

Comment: you can use before_filter to call  in every controller. Where order_items should be written in application controller in a method

Comment: have done it using before action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use before_filter to call in every controller. Where order_items should be written in application controller in a method.

Answer (score 0):

I thing your  @order_items is return the collection type , So please check  your @order_items object have data ?
by using this methods

.empty?  or .nil?

it return the true or false , you get you result.